# Why list contains more than n element in python?

Tags: python, list

I am novice in Python.
I would like to enter 10 elements into the list.
Below program appends 10 elements to each of the list.
But below program prints 11 objects in list why?
I got this program from http://www.learnpython.org/page/Basic%20Operators link.
I wanted to know `x = object()`, what does it mean?

```
x = object()
y = object()
i = 0
# change this code
x_list = [x]
y_list = [y]
while(i < 10):
    x_list.append((10))
    y_list.append(11)
    i = i + 1
#x_list = [x]
#y_list = [y]
big_list = x_list + y_list

print "x_list contains %d objects" % len(x_list) # prints 11 objects, #Why?
print "y_list contains %d objects" % len(y_list) # prints 11 objects, #Why?
print "big_list contains %d objects" % len(big_list)
print x_list.count(10)
print y_list.count(11)
    print big_list.count(10)
# testing code
if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10:
    print "Almost there..."
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10:
    print "Great!"
```

Comment: Hint: They want you to use the `*` and `+` operators in this exercise, not loops.

Comment: @lazy: I understood the point. Thanks for that help. But wanted to know if I will use `loop` is there any problem. Can't I achieve my goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [learnpython.org basic operators page](http://www.learnpython.org/page/Basic%20Operators) provides some examples of using arithmetic operators in different contexts, including lists. Based on quickly reading the tutorial in that page, probably the answer that the page authors were after would be:

```
x_list = [x] * 10
y_list = [y] * 10
big_list = x_list + y_list
```

Which would create a list with 10 x:s in it.

You were using a loop to do that, which is much more flexible way. A more pythonic way to fill a list by using a loop would be e.g. to use list comprehensions:

```
x_list = [x for i in xrange(10)]
```

or use a `for` loop, then you don't have to keep track of the index yourself:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    x_list.append(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

`x_list = [x]` => 1 object.
`while(i < 10):
    x_list.append((10))` => 10 objects (0 to 9)
So 11 is perfectly normal. You should have set `x_list = []` (empty list) not to have this 1st element.

Answer (score 3):

> Below program appends 10 elements to each of the list. But below program prints 11 objects in list why?

Because the list had 1 element in it before you started appending. The list `[x]` contains 1 element, `x`. 1 + 10 = 11.

> I wanted to know x = object(), what does it mean?

It means exactly what it says: "x shall be a name for the result of calling `object`". `object` is a class, so calling it creates an instance. An `object` instance is exactly what it sounds like - just an object, with nothing interesting about it.

Answer (score 1):

`object()` just generates a new instance of the class `object`. you first insert this element to `x_list`, then you add another 10 elements

Answer (score 0):

x_list contains X plus 10 times 10 = 11...

y_list - the same.

when you type `x_list = [x]` it means the list is initialized as a list with only `x` in it.